# Check if process is running, if not start it

Tags: batch

Looking to launch a file if its closed with a batch file that goes along these lines:

:start
if the file is not open then open it
Timeout 10
Goto start

Im not very good at programming

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the place to be asking for free scripts but since what you need can be easily accomplished, ill save you the trouble.

A very similar question was asked on
[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), and I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq program.exe" /FO CSV > search.log

FOR /F %%A IN (search.log) DO IF %%~zA EQU 0 GOTO end

start program.exe

:end

del search.log
```

Where it says "program.exe" change it to the name of the program your using.

Credit: Matt Lacey https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the "program" in question would be notepad. You copy the code below to notepad, save it with the name you want but with a *.bat extension and run it. The batch file would check if notepad is running every 10 seconds and if not it would start the process again...

```
@echo off
set ProgramPath=%windir%\notepad.exe

for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%ProgramPath%") do set "Program=%%~nxa" 

:Repeat
set Running=no
for /f %%a in ('tasklist') do if /i "%%a"=="%Program%" set Running=yes

if /i Not "%Running%"=="yes" start "" "%ProgramPath%"

timeout /t 10 > nul
goto :Repeat
```